# .NET. Programmatically check if directory has changed or perform checksum on directory

Tags: c#, directory

Can someone tell me an efficient way to check if a directory and its contents have changed using C#?  The program is not running all the time so FileWatcher is not an option.  Also, this test must be done quickly and need not be perfect, just pretty good.  By this I mean I'd be happy if I could quickly check that for a given directory, the same subdirectories were still present. And the same file names with the same file sizes.  I guess it might also be nice to verify the "modified date".  It's not necessary or desirable to open each file and verify contents. That would take too long.  I can easily save the info (file sizes, etc.) to a file and read it the next time I run the program.

The background for this is that I'm developing a search program to search our proprietary files.  I save the results to a JSON file and the next time the search is done, I simply read from JSON. Of course ONLY if the directory (or subdirectory) has not changed.

I've posted the code below that I currently use for checking.  It's way too slow.  The biggest time hog is the checking to see if all the directories match, but even the first line ("Directory.Exists") takes some time.

Please let me know if I can provide more details or clarification.

Thanks,

Dave

```
            if (Directory.Exists(directoryCache.DirectoryName) == false)
            return false;

        // look at sessZip
        ulong fileSize = 0;
        string[] sessZipEntries = Directory.GetFiles(directoryCache.DirectoryName,
    "*.sessZip", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (string fileName in sessZipEntries)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            fileSize += (ulong)fileInfo.Length;
        }

        if (fileSize != directoryCache.SessZipSize)
            return false;


        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryCache.DirectoryName);
        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            if (directoryCache.SubDirectoriesList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DirectoryName == directory) == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        foreach (DirectoryCacheItem subDir in directoryCache.SubDirectoriesList)
        {
            if (directories.Contains(subDir.DirectoryName) == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
```

Comment: Are you running your application on the same machine that contains the volume you're checking? That can have a significant impact on time.

Comment: `Directory.GetLastWriteTime()` might be useful here.

Comment: itsme86.  Unfortunately, the application much be run on a different machine.  I'm checking a networked drive.  Thanks for looking at my question

Comment: This still comes across as a "write my code for me" question. The expectation on Stack Overflow is that the person asking the question will have made _some_ attempt to solve their problem and have for some reason run into some _specific_ difficulty. As such, they will be able to (and are expected to) include a good [mcve] in their question showing what they've tried, and to explain in precise terms what _specifically_ they are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: Peter:  Not sure what you mean.  I've posted the code* in my question that works and calculates if a) subdirectories are the same, and b) total number of bytes are the same.  The code works. However, it's slow and I strongly suspect there are faster ways. Quite possibly there is functionality within the .NET framework itself.  Do you think possibly you're being unduly harsh?   *I suppose I could list the code for DirectoryCacheItem and give a complete example, but frankly, the snippet I give seems pretty clear.

Comment: Can you just use git

Comment: _"Not sure what you mean"_ -- then you haven't read [mcve]. Please do.

Comment: @Dave did you ever find a fast solution for this? I'm also looking to quickly detect if a folder's contents have changed, without calling Directory.GetFiles(), which is slow

Comment: @user3163495  The solution I found is what Tim mentions below (in marked answer) and I expanded upon in my own answer.   To be honest, I'd forgotten all about this problem. It's over 7 years old! :)  Perhaps there are faster ways today?  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to hash the contents of the folder and store that off. Then just compare it. MD5 should be sufficient.

If you want easier you can follow the MS example, but it isn't foolproof.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693036.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I'll check out the example in depth. I'll need to modify for my case, which is one directory, and one object, DirectoryCacheItem, that represent the directory structure at a previous time.  I see the example also uses, "GetFiles" which I suspect is where some of the slowness is.  It may be that I can't do a whole lot better than what I have.  It's just frustrating that the step to verify the directory hasn't changed takes longer than the actual looking up a value in the saved cache.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Marked as answer and see my answer if you want details of implementation.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Tim's answer (which I'm marking as answer), I was able to come up with a pretty good, fast solution for checking that the directory has not changed. Thanks Tim for the idea and link.  I have:

```
public bool VerifyCacheIntegrity()
    {
        if (_directoryCache == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_directoryCache.DirectoryName))
            return false;

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(_directoryCache.DirectoryName);
        FileInfo[] list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.sessZip", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        FileCompare myFileCompare = new FileCompare();


        return list1.SequenceEqual(_directoryCache.FileInfoLst, myFileCompare); 

    }
```

FileCompare is defined as:

```
internal class FileCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
{
    public FileCompare() { }

    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
    {
        return (f1.Name == f2.Name &&
                f1.Length == f2.Length);
    }

    // Return a hash that reflects the comparison criteria. According to the 
    // rules for IEqualityComparer<T>, if Equals is true, then the hash codes must
    // also be equal. Because equality as defined here is a simple value equality, not
    // reference identity, it is possible that two or more objects will produce the same
    // hash code.
    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
    {
        string s = String.Format("{0}{1}", fi.Name, fi.Length);
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Obviously, the FileCompare could be expanded to include "Modified Date" comparisons or anything else.  Finally, for completeness, I show how FileInfoLst is populated.  This is the list that ultimately goes into a file and provides a snapshot of what the directory structure looked like.

```
public bool BuildTree(string directory, string searchItem = null, List<string> matches = null, string searchField = null)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            return false;

        _directoryCache = BuildDirectoryCache(directory, searchItem, matches, searchField);

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory);

        FileInfo[] list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.sessZip", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        _directoryCache.FileInfoLst = list1;
        return true;
    }
```